# Flask Talisman get nonce to work. Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: python, html, flask, content-security-policy, nonce

I've been trying to implement the python3 plugin [Flask_Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman) into my current project. Everything seems to be working except the content security policy (CSP). The problem is that I need scripts (bootstrap, google reCaptcha, etc.) to be executed from my site, but they are being blocked by the CSP.

My old config looked like this:

```py
csp = {
    'default-src': [
        '\'self\''
        ],
    'script-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'unsafe-inline',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/',
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/',
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/',
        'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/'
        ],
    'frame-src': [
        'unsafe-inline',
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/', 
        'https://www.recaptcha.google.com.com/recaptcha/'
        ],
    'style-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/'
        ]
    }

Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

which didn't work.
So I switched over to using hashes, which was recommended online:

```py
csp = {
    'script-src': [
        '\'sha256-pyVP/WTBWg0xeYb2xYVwRtZnbyqX6sWurV0uPjEvCN8=\'',
        '\'sha256-fWJPdkYD1sLmgF1O8gp95DZx1j4F+AnK3vUr+ok3MQ8=\'',
        '\'sha256-6WSoVabpxgBYdB7f22nyWr5xcn/Gy4BzHFxng1Z4Gvk=\'',
        '\'sha256-wOhDwuiz1H/PNcPRBBYh/Udj5Jiune650+GU60FuIFI=\''
        ],
    'frame-src': [
        '\'sha256-6WSoVabpxgBYdB7f22nyWr5xcn/Gy4BzHFxng1Z4Gvk=\'',
        '\'sha256-bwxrUkAWabRJI1ius9X3I0XsglPBvIQ5uU/V2h/wuhc=\''
        ],
    'style-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/'
        ],
    'object-src': [
        '\'none\''
        ]
    }
   
Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

I also tried using the `unsafe-inline` tag, as well as `unsafe-hashed`, and many others, always with the same outcome:
`Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:`

In my last attempt, I implemented a nonce system, which now works with a function; it will create a nonce each time it's called, pass it to my index.html and tell the talisman where it is at. (I also tried using the `{{ csp_nonce() }}` [Docs example #6](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#example-6) function that is provided by the docs, but that didn't work.)

So:

```py
def getNonce():
    return os.urandom(16).hex()
```

and then in my flask route:

```py
return render_template('index.html', message=message, nonce=getNonce())
```

with the config:

```py
csp = {
    'script-src': '\'self\'',
    'frame-src': '\'self\'',
    'style-src': '\'self\'',
    'object-src': '\'none\''
    }

Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp, content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src', 'style-src']
```

as well as adding `nonce={{ nonce }}` to every script tag in my HTML.

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX" nonce="{{ nonce }}"></script>
```

Even though I tried over and over, I am still stuck on the "same" error message (only changing when I switch between unsafe-inline, hashes, or nonces):

[image: Error message]

So always the `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:`

If you know how to fix this, please let me know, because I don't know anymore. The website itself is working without a problem, but as soon as enabling the Flask Talisman CSP, everything seems to fall apart.

After reading the docs again, I read *`Note that the CSP directive (script-src in the example) to which the nonce-... source should be added needs to be defined explicitly.`*. So I tried re-adding the URL's back to the CSP (without using `unsafe-inline`). The new config now looks like this:

```py
newCsp = {
    'default-src': '\'self\'',
    'script-src': [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/',
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/',
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/',
        'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/'
        ],
    'frame-src': [
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/', 
        'https://www.recaptcha.google.com.com/recaptcha/'
        ],
    'style-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/'
        ],
    'object-src': '\'none\''
    }
```

Now the problem is that while the website can now retrieve all the scripts (and is working), and uses the nonces, it still throws this error:

[image: New error message]

or in text form:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ 'nonce-bykkHFtoKjMIXmjxP4M28B6lSmJMa9XA'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-h0FtDBdxOnu72uVQe4oUILMiGyexQqDT1jgToPa4Sog='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-pyVP/WTBWg0xeYb2xYVwRtZnbyqX6sWurV0uPjEvCN8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Which I can't explain, because when removing the URL's again, I am back to the old error.

Maybe some of you have another solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and using nonce was my solution, maybe this helps:

```
SELF = "'self'"
csp = {
        'default-src': SELF,
        'img-src': '*',
        'script-src': [SELF,],
        'style-src': [SELF,],
        'font-src': [SELF,],
    }

nonce_list = ['default-src', 'script-src']

talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp, content_security_policy_nonce_in=nonce_list)
```

and script as follows:

```
<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```